# Bonjour service is so late on iPad

Tags: ipad, bonjour

I met a strange problem when I make the bonjour develop on iPad.

The requirement is like this:

```
 a).I write the bonjour server on Mac and it works fine. 
    And iPad will conntect with this service by Wi-Fi. 
    This Wi-Fi network is created by this Mac(Internet sharing). 
    Thus once iPad joined into this Wi-Fi network, the bonjour browser
    program(which run in iPad) will find the service.
```

The steps:

```
 a).firstly I am sure that this client program works fine. 
    It could find the serivce.
 b).But I want to make this program are stable under any condition. So I take a detail 
    test.
 c).One of the testcase is:
          1). The client program already run on iPad, and could find the service.
          2). Then, I make "WLAN off" in setting item(I close the connect from iPad).
          3). Then, I make "WLAN on" and select the same Wi-Fi network.
```

The problem comes:

```
  a). I find, the cilent program find the bonjour service sometimes take
      so long time(max time even 7 minutes),sometimes several seconds.
  b). And this is only happened under the condition whhich WI-FI created 
      as "Internet sharing from Mac". If I create the Wi-Fi as 
      "None Internet share", I could always found the bonjoure service
      within about 20 seconds.
```

So, what's the difference between "Wi-Fi as none internet sharing and
internent shareing(I know iPad could go to internet by internet sharing from Mac"?

How to slove it?